# Repeating table in subreport

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, subreport

I have a table in a subreport that pulls from a database. It reads all data correctly, but now I want only the data connected to a specific course. How can I filter the results?

I added the ID of the course as a subreport link. But each ID has its own subreport, and I only want one table to contain all the data.

[image]

Here is also a preview of the table:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't add the ID as a sub report link instead you should add the ID in record selection formula.

Open the record selection formula and add as:

```
ID=yourvalue 
//if you want user to priovde value at runtime then add parameter
ID={?Parameter}
```

Comment: I get the same result, it only shows one line in the table and the sub report repeats

Comment: If you are retriving only one record then it should display correctly one more option is you may have created group and also where did you place the sub report?

Comment: I placed the subreport under a group. The group won't be repeated of course. But I wanna fill the table with more then only one line

Comment: With a cross table it shows me the right content. But the layout is useless.

Comment: If you are grouping and that grup has only one value then you won't get this issue

Comment: Everything worked fine it was only the problem with the linkers of the tables

Comment: I used the inner join

Comment: Can you show some sample data and also your preview instead of design

Comment: I added the preview!

Comment: Ok though you used inner join table is repeating...in that case it looks like your id field is attached to multiple values in other table...if you have axcess to databse then check for a dingle id how many values are retrived